White Screen on WP Login Page
can someone maybe help me.
When I try to go to the login page of my wp homepage the screen is only white. All other pages of the frontend are visble, but not the login page.
I did manage to start the debuging and it reads like this:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/htdocs/w01ba699/oebels-invest.de/wp-config.php:1) in /www/htdocs/w01ba699/oebels-invest.de/wp-content/plugins/advanced-iframe/advanced-iframe.php on line 399


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/htdocs/w01ba699/oebels-invest.de/wp-config.php:1) in /www/htdocs/w01ba699/oebels-invest.de/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1435


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/htdocs/w01ba699/oebels-invest.de/wp-config.php:1) in /www/htdocs/w01ba699/oebels-invest.de/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1438

I opend these up and the lines in question read
function aiAddHeader() {
           $devOptions = $this->getAiAdminOptions();
        
            // IE fix for cookies.
header('P3P: CP="ALL DSP NID CURa ADMa DEVa HISa OTPa OUR NOR NAV DEM"');
            
            AdvancedIframeHelper::check_debug_get_parameter();
            AdvancedIframeCookie::addCookieSameSite($devOptions['cookie_samesite_filter']);
        }

other page:
$x_redirect_by = apply_filters( 'x_redirect_by', $x_redirect_by, $status, $location );
        if ( is_string( $x_redirect_by ) ) {
                header( "X-Redirect-By: $x_redirect_by" );
        }

                  header( "Location: $location", true, $status );

        return true;
    }

I can't find the error here. I am very greatful for any advide

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php/. What's on line 1 of wp-config.php?
